# Имитация keyup в поле ввода

Tags: javascript, chrome-extension, firefox-extension

Создаю расширение для автоматизации действий на странице. Не удается сымитировать keyup.

Код имеет следующий вид:

```
$("span").click(function () {
    $('.basket-item-amount').val('1000');
    $('.basket-item-amount').trigger('keyup');
    $(".flat_button.basket-dobet").click();
});
```

Он абсолютно идентичен как для Chrome так и для Firefox. В консоле также выполняется как надо, но когда запускаю в виде расширения trigger('keyup') не срабатывает.

Какие есть варианты выйти из этого положения? На самом инпуте завязаны скрипты сайта, и только keyup вызывает их.

Comment: А куда вы этот код ставите? Чтобы он передавал обработчик на страницу его надо в contentscript вставлять, по идее должно работать. Если он в контенте, то возможно он загружается быстрее, чем span, и клик необходимо вешать на документ

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать  объект `KeyboardEvent`;
Пример:

```
var ev = new KeyboardEvent("keyup",{key:"f",code:"KeyF",target:input});
input.dispatchEvent(ev);
```

Comment: Код выполняется, но никакого результата не приносит.

Comment: А Вы уверены, что события вызывает keyup, а не keydown или input?

Comment: Конечно, специально проверил это в исходном коде.

Comment: Изменил     ответ   .